# Hibernate search with lucene for two tables

Tags: spring-mvc, lucene, hibernate-search

I have two tables CatalogueBase and CatalogueCopydetails now i am using Hibernate search for CatalogueBase table but i wanted to search even in CatalogueCopydetails table. This two tables are related with @ManyToOne (i.e CatalogueCopydetails using CatalogueBase id as foreign key), hear for one entry of CatalogueBase their will be 'n' numbers of CatalogueCopydetails

CatalogueBase POJO Class

```
@Indexed
@JsonAutoDetect
@Entity
@Table(name="catalogueBase")
public class CatalogueBase extends BaseObject implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    ......

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long   id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
         ....
```

CatalogueCopydetails POJO Class

```
@JsonAutoDetect
@Entity
@Table(name="cataloguecopydetails")
public class CatalogueCopyDetails extends BaseObject implements Serializable {  

    private CatalogueBase catalogueBase;
    ......
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="cataloguebaseid" , insertable=true, updatable=true,nullable=true)
    public CatalogueBase getCatalogueBase() {
        return catalogueBase;
    }
    public void setCatalogueBase(CatalogueBase catalogueBase) {
        this.catalogueBase = catalogueBase;
    }

    ......
```

at least how can i use @IndexedEmbedded for this scenario (i don't think i can use    @IndexedEmbedded because CatalogueBase have no relation to CatalogueCopyDetails like OneToOne or OneToMany etc only CatalogueCopyDetails references CatalogueBase )

how can i do this..?, any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would of course be to make the relation bidirectional. Is there a good reason why you don't want to do that? The other thing you could do is to add @Indexed to CatalogueCopyDetails as well and use @IndexedEmbedded on CatalogueBase. You could then write a query using the CatalogueCopyDetails index. Whether this works will depend on your use case and what you actually want as result of query.

Comment: thanks for your replay, i did as you said but it does't allow to add data on parent table

Comment: What do you mean with "but it does't allow to add data on parent table"?